# Removing Blue Border around a Button After Click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

here is the problematic bit of code

```css
:root {
  --color-foreground-text-main: rgb(255, 72, 142);
  --color-foreground-text-sub: rgb(0, 114, 153);
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#cover {
  background: #222 url('Resources/img/cover.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: var(--color-foreground-text-main);
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#cover-caption {
  width: 100%;
}

#subscribe-button {
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--color-foreground-text-main);
  color: white;
  outline: 0;
}

#subscribe-button:hover {
  background: var(--color-foreground-text-sub);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--Mandatory meta tags-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Custom Styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="SP_BaseStyle.css" />
  <title>School Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="cover">
    <div id="cover-caption">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-12">
          <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="p-0 pr-1 pb-1 m-0 
                        col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
              <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="George Smith">
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 m-0 pr-1 pb-1 
                        col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
              <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="george.smith@email.com">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg mb-1
                        col-12 col-md-2" id="subscribe-button">Subscribe!</button>
          </div>
          <a href="#nav-main" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" role="button">&darr;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Bootstrap functionality -->
  <script>
    // Initialize tooltip component
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })

    // Initialize popover component
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

after clicking the button out of nowhere a dark blue outline appears around the button. I looked around forums and the Bootstrap Docs about it but I cannot seem to find a way to change it's color or remove it altogether

I have tried setting the outline and the box shadow without any success.

NOTE: I know it is a visual queue that should not be removed and prefer just changing the color of it but if I cannot do it other way I would want to remove it internally and add it in CSS.

EDIT: Just for clarification we are talking about the 'subscribe' button not the arrow button. I am adding the code with the suggested changes. Also removing the border for clarity.

Comment: `outline: 0` lol

Comment: @pedram it does not work even with that. I still see the light blue border and a dark blue outline(which I want gone)

Comment: I removed the border and tried the outline property, sadly it does not do anything. it happens both on Chrome and on Edge so it is not browser specific.

Comment: check updated answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought it was `outline` but not, of course i didn't saw your code, but after i see, the problem is here:

```
border: 2px var(--color-foreground-text-sub) solid;
```

remove this line. that's all.

**Edit:** and after click, override this:

```
.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-foreground-text-main: rgb(255, 72, 142);
  --color-foreground-text-sub: rgb(0, 114, 153);
}

.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#cover {
  background: #222 url('Resources/img/cover.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: var(--color-foreground-text-main);
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#cover-caption {
  width: 100%;
}

#subscribe-button {
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--color-foreground-text-main);
  color: white;
  outline: 0;
}

#subscribe-button:hover {
  background: var(--color-foreground-text-sub);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--Mandatory meta tags-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Custom Styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="SP_BaseStyle.css" />
  <title>School Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="cover">
    <div id="cover-caption">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-12">
          <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="p-0 pr-1 pb-1 m-0 
                        col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
              <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="George Smith">
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 m-0 pr-1 pb-1 
                        col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
              <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="george.smith@email.com">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg mb-1
                        col-12 col-md-2" id="subscribe-button">Subscribe!</button>
          </div>
          <a href="#nav-main" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" role="button">&darr;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Bootstrap functionality -->
  <script>
    // Initialize tooltip component
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })

    // Initialize popover component
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Just add this to your css:

```
button:focus {outline:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's small property named "outline" is mostly placed in pseudo classes. So to avoid it you may use `outline:none` or `outline:0`